# How to match a full string, instead of partial string?

Tags: python, regex

```
pattern = (1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12)

str = '11'
```

This only matches '1', not '11'. How to match the full '11'? I changed it to:

```
pattern = (?:1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12)
```

It is the same.

I am testing here first:

https://regex101.com/

Comment: Could you please post the code which you are using for performing these tests?

Comment: Put the longer inputs in the front - `(10|11|12|1|2|3)` instead of `(1|2|3|10|11|12)`. The earlier an option is in the chain of 'or's, the more precedence it takes, because the check will short-circuit.

Comment: In fact, your alternation should now match both 1 and 11.  Please include the relevant Python code here.

Comment: It matches `1`, so it stops looking, since a regex won't give you a match for all the ways in which it matches, just the first way in which it matches. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Use boundary to match whole string like `\b11\b`

Comment: @AmbrishPathak, yes, I can use '^' and '$' to mark the boundary.

Comment: Btw, just a note that regex doesn't really have an order of precedent, each construct performs an atomic action and from left to right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is matching `1` instead of `11` because you have `1` before `11` in your alternation. If you use `re.findall` then it will match `1` **twice** for input string `11`.

However to match numbers from 1 to 12 you can avoid alternation and use:

```
\b[1-9]|1[0-2]?\b
```

It is safer to use **word boundary** to avoid matching within word digits.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kqj9PP/2)

Answer (score 0):

Regex always matches left before right.
On an alternation you'd put the longest first.

However, factoring should take precedense.

`(1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12)`

then it turns into

`1[012]?|[2-9]`

https://regex101.com/r/qmlKr0/1

I purposely didn't add boundary parts as
everybody has their own preference.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean this solution?

```py
[\d]+
```